# In python how to escape the special char when insert data into the SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql-server

I want to insert a html file into the SQL Server, but there there are some special char in the document, how can I escape the special chars?

Below is my code:

```
import pymssql
import os
txt_file = u'E:/project/robot_framework/xxxx/logs/log-20170318-143134.html'
file_name = os.path.split(txt_file)[1]
conn = pymssql.connect(host='192.168.0.888',user='sa',password='xxxxx',database='Automation')
content = open(txt_file, 'r')
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = "insert into log_file (File_Name,RunID,File_VARCHAR_Content) values('%s',1,'%s')" % (file_name, content.readlines())
cur.execute(sql)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

but I got the errors:

> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:\project\robot_framework\PythonDemo\src\try.py", line 20, in
> >     
> >         cur.execute(sql)   File "pymssql.pyx", line 464, in pymssql.Cursor.execute (pymssql.c:7491) pymssql.ProgrammingError:
> >     (102, "Incorrect syntax near '<'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity
> >     15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL
> >     Server\nDB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server
> >     error: Check messages from the SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python regular expression library "re".

```
import re
txt_file = u'E:/project/robot_framework/xxxx/logs/log-20170318-143134.html'
escaped_string = re.escape(txt_file)
```

Comment: Hey Mustafa, I created this escaped_string but still, I am unable to insert this String to my microsoft sql server... any clue why this happens?

Comment: downvoted because `re.escape` escapes special characters in with respect to regular expressions, not sql statements.

Comment: His problem was special characters in txt file so he don't need to escape sql statements for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just because this was my first search result on startpage:

Do not change this code if you do not know what it does!

```
conn = pymssql.connect(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',user='xxxxxxx',password='xxxxx',database='Whatever')
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT id,KartenUid FROM Benutzer WHERE KartenUid=%s;",("b99cec01"))
row=c.fetchone()
#row=(UUID('6533f7d3-f190-45fd-95e0-72e3add0e9db'), 'b99cec01')
c.execute("SELECT id,KartenUid FROM Benutzer WHERE KartenUid=%s;",("b99cec01; DROP TABLE Benutzer;"))
row=c.fetchone()
#row=None
c.execute("SELECT id,KartenUid FROM Benutzer WHERE KartenUid=%s;",("b99cec01"))
row=c.fetchone()
#row=(UUID('6533f7d3-f190-45fd-95e0-72e3add0e9db'), 'b99cec01')
```

So to prevent SQL injection (and other escape problems) please use the `pymssql.Cursor.execute(sql, paramsAsTuple)` method (See [readTheDocs](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/ref/pymssql.html#pymssql.Cursor.execute)).